# Make CMake not search for Python components on reconfigure

Tags: cmake, googletest

I added googletest to my build using `FetchContent` like this:

```
FetchContent_Declare(googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest
    GIT_TAG main
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
```

But after I did this, each time CMake needs to rerun its configure/generate steps it takes about ~25 seconds. This is really interfering with my workflow when making iterative changes to the build.

```
C:\NSEW>cmake --build .
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...

   | It takes about 20 seconds until the following output is shown |

-- Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)
-- Found SFML 2.5.1 in C:/install/lib/cmake/SFML
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/NSEW
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
ninja: no work to do.
```

googletest has an optional Python dependency but since Python isn't installed, CMake tries every possible installation path which takes very long. CMake appears to do this search on every reconfigure. How to stop CMake from doing this very slow search for a component I don't need?

I tried to set the cache variable `Python_EXECUTABLE` to `NO` / `Python-NOTFOUND` but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable any non-`REQUIRED` `find_package(PackageName)` command using [`CMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_<PackageName>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_PackageName.html). This variable has existed since at least CMake 3.0, so this will work in general.

You can set it just before `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` and then `unset()` it afterward. Otherwise, just set `CMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_Python=TRUE` (and/or `...Python3`) at the `cmake` command line.

Answer (score 0):

The `FindPython` module that googletest/CMake uses has a `Python_FIND_IMPLEMENTATIONS` variable you can configure. This is an allow list of what Python implementations CMake should look for.

If you configure this to an empty string it should not spend any time searching for a Python installation.

```
cmake -DPython_FIND_IMPLEMENTATIONS:STRING="" <build directory>
```